# How to make a monitor more “anti-glare”?

Tags: monitors

I’m surprised why this question isn’t asked, spent hours now trying to get an answer, but couldn’t find it.

Im working in a very bright room, and cannot really do much about it. My monitor is facing northwest, and there are windows northwest, and southwest. Big floor to ceiling ones, 2, and 3 metres wide.

I’m having a Philips 245E1S. It was £150. I love it, perfect in every way. Even though it’s max brightness is 250 nits, the anti glare cover is so good that I can work on it even with direct sunshine. But it’s too small with its 24 inches.

I need my monitor for programming, an ultra wide one because I need tons of columns.

I bought 3 monitors so far, sent all of them back.

I bought a Philips 34 21:9 VA monitor. I would never buy va again, terrible text rendering, and I was surprised when I read that VAs have blacker blacks. Mine was grey at its best. But the anti flare finish was alright.

I bought a BenQ Mobiuz 34 monitor. It’s a junk. Very dim, very shiny, terrible colours.

I bought a DELL U4021QW. Loved it, but it was like mirror.

So far my 24 Philips seems the best despite not having any fancy stuff in it or HDR. The DELL is 11 times the cost of the original Philips, and wasn’t good enough.

I’m looking for a way to make a monitor more matte. I was wondering if there are any sort of spray or cream (?) that can make a monitor more matte.

Answer (score 0):

A [search](https://www.markevanstech.com/best-anti-glare-screen-protector-for-computer-monitor/) for "anti-glare filter for computer monitor" came up with a few interesting results.

The linked site is a compilation of a few products, along with links on Amazon for purchase. It appears that the anti-glare feature is also combined with a privacy aspect, in which observers beyond 18° from perpendicular to the screen will see little to nothing.

The descriptions also reference a matte finish versus a shiny finish, reversible, allowing for glare reduction when the matte side is toward the viewer.

Comment: I was looking into that too, but there doesn’t seem to be options for large as 40” screens